# Python socket script. How to send data to specific client

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I'm I created a server/client python script that uses socks. I'm trying to send data to a specific client. I would image I would have to load connected ip's into array but I don't know how to send data to specific client. I'v uploaded my code to pastebin as I figured that might help get the best answer. http://pastebin.com/en863i1s

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to close the `clientsocket`.
You can have more connections open. Each one is an established connection.

To send data to a specific client just call the `.sendall(...)` method (more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall)) of the specific client socket object.

Btw if you're trying to implement a traditional client/server model for production and not for learning purposes, try to not reinvent the wheel and use something like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) or the builtin [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer now I can complete my project :) I will up vote when I get enough rep.